# How do I pull down docker images within a container?

Tags: docker

I have read this was a bad idea but I don't know how else to accomplish the following.

I am trying to spin up a container with security tools (I can get these with curl/wget/git), pull down some images from a registry (Docker Hub/Quay), then run the security tool on those images. Because it is within a container (instead of VM) and requires pulling down images, it's like I need to have docker in docker.

How can this be done?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/downloading-docker-images-from-docker-hub-without-using-docker#

Comment: But what is your main purpose when doing that? what will you got? May be it has a better way to solve your problem.